# The word "Array" gets printed instead of the values of the rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Okay,i'm a newbie to CI and MySQL. This is my code:

```
<?php
class Trail2 extends CI_Controller{

public function boo() {

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $ret="SELECT * from posts";
    $query=$this->db->query($ret);
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        echo br(1);
        echo $row;
    }   
}

}

?>
```

and this returns the word "Array" in place of the values of the rows. I cant seem to figure out why though. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
var_dump($row);
```

instead of

```
echo $row;
```

and if you just want to see the values of the array you can do something like the following

```
for ($var = 0; $var < sizeof($row); $var++) echo $row[$var].", ";
```

Answer (score 5):

`$row` is an array. use `$row['column']` to access a single column. to see what the array looks like, you can use `print_r($row)` or `var_dump($row)`