# PHP array printing 'array' instead of values.

Tags: php

I am using this code but can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
            $value=stripslashes($value);
        if ($key=='extras') {       
            if (is_array($_POST['extras'])) {
                print "<tr><td><code>$key</code></td><td>";
                foreach ($_POST['extras'] as $value) {
                print "<i>$value</i><br />";
                }
                print "</td></tr>";
                } 
            else {
                print "<tr><td><code>$key</code></td><td><i>$value</i></td></tr>\n";
                }
            } 
        else {
            print "<tr><td><code>$key</code></td><td><i>$value</i></td></tr>\n";
        }
    } // end foreach
}
```

It prints prgm 'array' in table instead of values inside array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398623/the-word-array-gets-printed-instead-of-the-values-of-the-rows?rq=1

Comment: @u_mulder  I think it's not going inside if (is_array($_POST['extras']))

Comment: Then find out where it happens

Comment: it's going inside else, I'm not able to figure it out, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) would be at least a way to gain some insight into the structure of the array.

Comment: I think it's not going inside if (is_array($_POST['extras']))

Comment: print_r is definitely your friend here!

Comment: this is not working, please help!!

Comment: @user2876449 : could you maybe post how you are attempting to use `print_r()`? I would first just call `print_r($_POST)` to see the structure of the POST array.

Comment: this worked when i changed if (is_array($_POST['extras'])) to if (is_array($value))