# Codeigniter Rest Server JSON multidimension issue

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-restserver

I'm using Codeigniter rest server to create an api. one of my clients is sending the following JSON array to my api

```
    {
     "code": "TEST",
     "store": "DBNG0024",
     "total": "50.00",
     "items": [{ "code":"121", "descr":"Pizza 1", "value":"50", "qty":"1",    "dept":"1"}]
    }
```

In the rest server documentation is says you can access the data like:

```
   function client_post()
   {
      $code = $this->post('code');
      $store_code = $this->post('store');
      $total = $this->post('total');

      $data = array('code' => $this->post('code'), 'store' => $this->post('store'), 'status' => 'invalid', 'value' => '0', 'message' => 'code is invalid');

      $this->response($data);
   }
```

This works perfectly. Now the problem I'm having is that I cant access the multidimensional data "items": [{ "code":"121", "descr":"Pizza 1", "value":"50", "qty":"1",    "dept":"1"}]

I have tried the following

```
    $items = json_decode($this->post(‘items’)); - Prints nothing
    $items = $this->post(‘items’); - prints the word Array
```

if I print the post data like this print_r($_POST,true); the below is what is printed

```
    Array ( [code] => 1234 [store] => 1234 [total] => 1234 [items] => Array )
```

Can anyone assist me with finding a way to access the $items array data

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are getting items as Array on print, you can loop through it by accessing its key value pair

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $key=>$value)
{
  echo 'Key =>'.$key.'|---| Value =>'.$value;
}
```

Hope this help,let me know if you are stuck somewhere.

Edited :
Try this one i you might to json_decode your complete POSTED data..try below code

```
// $json will contain your posted data
$json = '{"code": "TEST","store": "DBNG0024","total": "50.00","items": [{ "code":"121", "descr":"Pizza 1", "value":"50", "qty":"1","dept":"1"}]}';
        $items = json_decode($json)->items;

        "qty"=>"1", "dept"=>"1"];
        foreach($items[0] as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo 'Key =>'.$key.':: Value =>'.$value;
            echo '<br/>';
        }
```

Comment: Hi, i did try this and I get the below error - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How would I get the post data, its being sent to us by another company which is accessing our API Url

Comment: If they are posting you can just use $this->post('json')

Comment: I don't have this part - $json = '{"code": "TEST","store": "DBNG0024","total": "50.00","items": [{ "code":"121", "descr":"Pizza 1", "value":"50", "qty":"1","dept":"1"}]}'; its sent to the API url in JSON Array format

Comment: as you told you have $_POST which is printing the data
Then you can directly json_decode($_POST) and it should work

Comment: i get this error - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: what does this gives you print_r($_POST['items'])

Comment: i have a feeling its an issue with the codeigniter-restserver that I'm using. the json data is decoded by the rest controller and than I access the data using $_POST['code']......   I'm thinking that the restserver controll does not handle multidimensional json arrays... is this possibly and how would it be corrected...  or I'm I completely wrong here

Comment: print_r($_POST['items']) - returns the word Array

Comment: print_r(json_decode($_POST['items'])) ?? Check this

Comment: this returned nothing

Comment: Then i guess your items variable has nothing posted...Kindly check if everything is posted correctly to you

Comment: why would the items be an issue but I can access the code, store and totals fine.....  you don't think it could have some to do with the restserver I'm using....  here is a link to it if that helps - https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: Those are giving you values because they have some values set. If $this->post('items') prints nothing to you then it has nothing to print. Also it has nothing to do with rest server you are using

Comment: that's my problem, I have confirmed that items does have values.

Comment: thanks anyways Zeeshan, will keep looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Usually, after decode JSON, it silently becames an sibling of `stdClass`.
If you are able to retrieve the values `code`, `store_code` and `total` as an `$_POST`, than you must be able to retrieve `items` as well.

```
$code  = $this->post('code');
$items = json_decode($this->post('items'));

foreach($items as $item)
   echo $item->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$items = $this->post(‘items’);` is the right way to access "items", kindly check this link [Send a raw json value to rest controller](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/253#). Maybe you are printing the array in the wrong way, please check this link too [The word “Array” gets printed instead of the values of the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398623/the-word-array-gets-printed-instead-of-the-values-of-the-rows)

Comment: thank you for your comment, will check out the links.